# Tables with error message

Tags: tables, errors

I am trying to make a table (which has worked perfectly before, I'm only using slightly different column headings).

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|p{1.8m}|p{1.2cm}|p{1.2cm}|p{1.2cm}|p{1.2cm}|p{1.2cm}|p{1.2cm}|}
\hline
Treatment Group & $\overline{x}$ T8 & $\sigma$ T8 & $\overline{x}$ T10 & $\sigma$ T10 & $\overline{x}$ T12 & $\sigma$ T12\\
\hline
\hline
Contol & 0.0244 & 0.00838 & 0.0306 & 0.01197 & 0.0368 & 0.02121\\
\hline
HSP27 & 0.0515 & 0.04647 & 0.04133 & 0.02856 & 0.042 & 0.02648 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The error is highlighting the 3rd line starting 'Treatment Group', and saying...

```
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again>
```

Comment: p{1.8m} is perhaps a tad too big! ;-)

Comment: welcome to the site, answer below but please try to always post complete documents as above (which allows you to check the posit really is an example of the problem) your original version was missing a `{` after `|p{1.8cm}` so gave a completely different error message. I fixed it this time:-)

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  `m` is not a known unit for TeX, I think you meant `cm`.  Then next line of the error message shows you the `m`.  You see on line 3, because that is the first time the column specification is used.

Answer (score 1):

You have used `m` instead of `cm` in the first column `|p{1.8m}`